# Updating an environment variable inside a docker

Tags: bash, go, dockerfile

I'm trying to pass environment variable between two test runs initiated from a bash file, to keep track of total sum of the `failed-` and `passed` tests. This is all run within a container.
But I'm not able to update the env var for some reason.

**bash file**

```
formatOutput() {
  sed -e ''/FAILED/s//$(printf "\033[31mFAILED\033[0m")/'' -e ''/PASSED/s//$(printf "\033[32mPASSED\033[0m")/''
}
exitCodes=()

TestListNetworks() {
  echo "TestListNetworks tests..."
    local CVN_PID=$(StartCVN "vrrp")
    LoadData "listNetworks.sql"
    ./cloud-volumes-network-client "--profile=listNetworks" | formatOutput
    local status=$?
    Flush
    kill -9 $CVN_PID
    exitCodes+=($status)
}

TestInfrastructure() {
  echo "TestInfrastructure tests..."
    local CVN_PID=$(StartCVN "vrrp")
    ./cloud-volumes-network-client "--profile=infrastructure" testCounts | formatOutput
    local status=$?
    kill -9 $CVN_PID
    exitCodes+=($status)
}

# running tests synchronously
TestListNetworks
TestInfrastructure

for exitCode in "${exitCodes[@]}"; do
  if [ "$exitCode" -eq "1" ]; then
      echo "Integration tests failed"
      exit "$exitCode"
  fi
done
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM mariadb/server:10.3.9

ENV FAILED_TESTS=$FAILED_TESTS
ENV SUCCESSFUL_TESTS=$SUCCESSFUL_TESTS

COPY ./build/linux/bin/cloud-volumes-network /
COPY ./build/linux/bin/cloud-volumes-network-client /

RUN mkdir -p /scripts/
ADD ./tests/scripts /

RUN chmod +x /*.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "./setup.sh"]
```

**Go Function**

```
func executeTests(testFunctionsList []func(cvn cvn.CVN) error, printCounters bool) error {
    cvnNew := cvn.New("x-corr-man")

    failedTests := getEnvAsInt("FAILED_TESTS", 0)
    passedTests := getEnvAsInt("SUCCESSFUL_TESTS", 0)
    // TODO: implement logic for skipped tests
    fmt.Printf("failedTests->before: %d\n", failedTests)
    fmt.Printf("failedTests->before: %d\n", passedTests)

    for _, executeTestFunction := range testFunctionsList {
        if err := executeTestFunction(cvnNew); err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("\tFAILED - %s: %s\n", extractFunctionName(executeTestFunction), err.Error())
            failedTests++
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("\tPASSED - %s\n", extractFunctionName(executeTestFunction))
            passedTests++
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("failedTests->after: %d\n", failedTests)
    fmt.Printf("failedTests->after: %d\n", passedTests)

    os.Setenv("FAILED_TESTS", strconv.Itoa(failedTests))
    os.Setenv("SUCCESSFUL_TESTS", strconv.Itoa(passedTests))

    //countersString := "\nFailed tests: %d\nSuccessful tests: %d\nSkipped tests: 0", failedTests, passedTests
    if printCounters {
        if failedTests > 0 {
            return errors.Errorf("\nFailed tests: %d\nSuccessful tests: %d\nSkipped tests: 0", failedTests, passedTests)
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nFailed tests: %d\nSuccessful tests: %d\nSkipped tests: 0\n", failedTests, passedTests)
        return nil
    } else {
        if failedTests > 0 {
            return errors.New("")
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Environment variables are process-level: setting yours sets *yours*, and that's all. When you create a new process, you provide the new process with its environment, including all of its variables. This can be a fresh new empty set, or a copy of yours: the process gets created, and now it has *its* variables. It can change them all it wants but none of that will affect *your* process as your process's variables are private to your process.

Comment: @torek get you, is there option in achieving what I'm trying to achieve?
Which basically is to pas results from former test runs to the next run, and have the last run print out the total results for all the runs?

Comment: You must send data on some communications channel: pipes, sockets, standard output, files, etc.